# Probability of another 3 integers with same sum and product as the first 3 integers

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, probability-theory, diophantine-equations

Let us suppose $3$ integers are selected at random from a large range, say $$-1000\leq x\leq y\leq z\leq 1000$$

Now, we define the sum and product:
$$\begin{align*}s&=x+y+z \\p&=xyz\end{align*}$$

($s$ and $p$ will not be equal in most cases, sorry for the confusion)

**What is the probability that there exists another solution for $(x,y,z)$ that satisfies above 3 equations?** (reordering of x, y and z not allowed)

My friend gave me this question, and I have no idea where to start. If we limit ourselves to positive integers, is there a unique solution, or not?

Comment: If reordering is not allowed then you could write the first constraint as $-1000\le x \le y \le z \le 1000$.

Comment: Among positive integers $1+5+8=2+2+10$ and $1\times5\times8 =2 \times 2 \times 10$ and there are more examples

Comment: @Henry Unfortunately not quite what the question is asking. It's asking for $xyz=x+y+z$.

Comment: @Emrakul You may be correct but I read the question as looking for duplicate pairs of $s$ and $p$ but not requiring $s=p$

Comment: @Henry The title says "same sum and product", which is why I concluded that, though I agree it is mildly unclear.

Comment: @Emrakul Sorry for not stating it clearing, but Henry is right.

Comment: @Stef Yes, I could, but does it benefit in any way?

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code No, it is only a matter of a more compact presentation of the constraints.

Comment: @Stef Okay, I'll do it.